# Image styles not working, uploads to to files directory

Tags: media

Image styles are not being applied. I have the /files/ directory set to CHMOD 777, GD Library is installed. When you upload an image, it just goes to the /files/ directory, none of the styles are generated into their styles folder. Reports -> status report is clean. Image uploads, but it stays in files directory, no thumbnails are generated, all paths are broken to the image even to the thumbnail in the Media page.

Hosted on AWS EC2 Linux/Apache

.htaccess in /files dir:

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You might not have necessary rights for the folders inside /files/, in this case /files/styles. Try chmod 775 -R </path/to/files_dir>

Comment: I used chmod -R 777 on the entire folder, Drupal is also not complaining about permissions in the Status Report...

Comment: It can be a problem with .htaccess file in sites/default/files directory, it depends on your host provider

Comment: I'll add additional info

Comment: confirm if 777 permission of `'sites/default/files'` are recursive and cross verify permissions of `'sites/default/files/styles'` directory, because image styles are stored inside this directory. Also check Drupal Logs to check failure of image style generation. Also please provide Drupal version you're using.

Comment: it's drupal 7, applied 777 to /files directory reclusively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's because you do not have the correct folder owner/group.**

You need to `cd` into your `/sites` folder. Once there:

If you're using Ubuntu do:

`sudo chown www-data:www-data -R default`

For CentOS it's:

`sudo chown apache:apache -R default` and [disable SELinux](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223327/drupal-files-folder-owner-group-for-centos#answer-223336)

---

**PS:** Never give your files folders permission of 777, set it to 775

Comment: If file permissions are set to 777, it means that every one can do everything. Changing the permissions like suggested is a good thing to do, but wont solve the problem.

Comment: @googletorp `but wont solve the problem` of course not, that's why it's a [PS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postscript)

Comment: @googletorp perhaps you meant to place your comment on the [other answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222611/image-styles-not-working-uploads-to-to-files-directory/223643?noredirect=1#answer-223640)?

Comment: did not make a difference. Images are still uploaded broken. SELinux seems to be disabled by default on AWS

Comment: @keeg, since you accepted my answer by clicking on the ✅, I take it you got it to work?

Comment: Yes there was another setting along with the permissions fixed it

Comment: For those in the same boat, make sure that  "Default download method" is set to "Private local files served by Drupal" in Configuration -> Media -> File System if using locally stored images

Comment: @keeg, you must of downloaded some contrib module that added another option or something, because in fresh Drupal installs of 7 & 8 for "default download method" [there is only one option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lk3f.png): `Public local files served by the webserver.` which cannot be unselected.

Comment: Possibly, I'm migrating a site I didn't dev, not sure of all the different modules as there is almost 150 of them..

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, provide 775 permission to files folder. `chmod 775 -rf sites/default/files/`
- Custom image styles(created by you) are stored in files/styles directory. To have an image style, create it from `/admin/config/media/image-styles`.
- If you are searching for the images you uploaded, they are placed in the directory mentioned in field storage structure which you can see from manage field of a content type under **File Directory**. Ex- `/admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/node.article.field_image`. By Default, [date:custom:Y]-[date:custom:m] is set in "File Directory".

Hope, it makes sense to you. Sorry, for 777 it's 775