# Drupal files folder owner/group for CentOS?

Tags: 7, files

This is my first time installing Drupal on CentOS. I know for Ubuntu it needs to be `www-data` as the /files folder owner, but what is it for CentOS?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced with this issue before, it was because of [SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) on CentOS, So you should try to [Disable SELinux on Centos](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html)

> From the command line, you can edit the /etc/sysconfig/selinux file.
>   This file is a symlink to /etc/selinux/config. The configuration file
>   is self-explanatory. Changing the value of SELINUX or SELINUXTYPE
>   changes the state of SELinux and the name of the policy to be used the
>   next time the system boots.

```
[root@host2a ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted

# SETLOCALDEFS= Check local definition changes
SETLOCALDEFS=0
```

Change it from `SELINUX=permissive` to `SELINUX=disabled`

Once you have saved the changes `sudo shutdown -r now` to restart now.

---

Also you can disable it temporary ( until next restarting ) with

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

[How to Disable SELinux](https://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2016/01/14/disabling-selinux-on-centos-7/)

Comment: OMG, big thank you. I've been going around in circles for 2 hours.

Comment: **For future readers:** You still need `apache` as owner/group as per @yogesh answer

Comment: @NoSssweat you're welcome my friend, I remember I spend some hours to find this solution and now I transmit it to you. . we are here to help each others.

Answer (score 2):

In CentOS, Apache/HTTPD username is normally [`apache`](https://serverfault.com/a/416239/172416). During installation, `apache` user should have read-write access to `sites/default` directory.

After installation, `apache` user should have read-write access to the `sites/default/files` directory. Check [Drupal Docs for more details on file permissions](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924#configuration-examples).

***Note:*** If giving permissions doesn't help, make sure [`SELinux`](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) is disabled. Check [@zhilevan](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/7212/zhilevan)'s [ans above](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223336/678).

Comment: [I changed it to apache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZPtl.jpg) and even gave it 777 (for testing purposes) and still getting the same file system error.

Comment: Did you tried with 'Proceed with the installation' or just refreshed the page?

Comment: If giving permissions to `sites/default` directory doesn't work, then try creating `files` directory and `settings.php` file inside it and giving these permissions. That should work

Comment: [I did that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSnIL.jpg) while the settings file error is now gone, the file system error is still showing up.

Comment: What is the error you're getting now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50301/discussion-between-yogesh-and-no-sssweat).